# Why camera not showing on Qt app using libvlc on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, video, vlc, qt, camera

My camera is not showing up on the Qt app by using the `libvlc` on the Virtualbox. I'm getting the below error when I debug that the camera can't show on the Qt app.

```
[00007fe3b8098480] main video output error: video output creation failed
[00007fe3d404c610] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[h264 @ 0x7fe3c806fd40] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7fe3c806fd40] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7fe3c806fd40] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fe3c806fd40] no frame!
```

Comment: Are you trying to record your webcam, record your screen, or are you trying to play a video?

Comment: thanks for reply, yes i have try to stream camera on player it's work but still error on Qt

Comment: Does at least `cheese -d /dev/video0` work?